# JQuery conditional to viewport with event listener?

Tags: jquery

This is my external script.

```
$(function(){
    $("#logo").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({paddingTop:"0px",paddingBottom:"20px"},200);
        },function(){
            $(this).animate({paddingTop:"20px",paddingBottom:"0"},200);
            });
    });
```

How can I execute this action only when the browser window is greater than 1100px even if the user scales the browser window on his own without needing to refresh the page?

Comment: Just check the browser width in the event handler?

Comment: It adds a large amount of lag on the script once the browser resizes. Is there a way to executive the external script based on viewport?

Comment: You mean resizing the browser becomes laggy? That shouldn't be, because the handler is not called on resize. The handler is only run when someone hovers over `#logo` and reading the browser width should not be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1100px)
        //do something
}
```

Be careful if you are using media queries though because sometimes css and jquery will fire a few pixels out of sync. If you are using a media query, it is better to take a css element and test it.